# Grails REST XML API definition

Tags: rest, grails

Striving to ship a well documented application, I'm looking for a good way to describe a REST API for my Grails Application users.

I know that REST calls should be simple enough to be described by examples, but it doesn't feel formal enough.

I've spent a couple of hours looking for a solution suggested by other Grails users, but didn't find a neat solution besides a recommendation to use WADL or WSDL 2.0

[This](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restwsdl/) looks like a good direction, but there must be a simple way to do it in Grails.

I'd appreciate some guidance for a process to generate a REST API based on my model objects preferably with the ability to filter or control the exposed fields, plus, a nice graphical way to present it (something like the XSD Eclipse plugin)

Thanks!
Guy

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to avoid WADL or WSDL for API documentation, you can see this question where I explained my reasons: [Why the slow WADL uptake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452750/why-the-slow-wadl-uptake).

WADL or WSDL are usually used for automatic client code generation, they are not human readable documentation. I don't think WADL or WSDL are very useful for a user to figure out how to consume the resources correctly.

I prefer the good old html documentation, for example I like the way [twitter](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-API-Documentation) documented their API

If you insist on automatic generation of resources documentation I can recommend on the [ATOM service document](http://bitworking.org/projects/atom/draft-ietf-atompub-protocol-14.html#appdocs). Many REST framework can generate it automatically based on the resources annotations. (e.g. Apache Wink)

Comment: Thanks, for an automatic human readable client documentation I've dug a little and found http://enunciate.codehaus.org/ for Java, I wonder if there is an equivalent tool for grails

Comment: Check out the following getting started http://enunciate.codehaus.org/getting_started.html and the example http://enunciate.codehaus.org/wannabecool/step1/index.html

Comment: your link to twitter documentation is broken. can you update?