# Is there a Relaxer for .NET? Is Relaxer alive? Is RelaxNG viable?

Tags: c#, javascript, relaxng, relaxer

I read about Relaxer, the thing that compiles .RNG to Java classes. BBut the website, http://www.relaxer.org/, is dead.

**Q1:**
Is Relaxer alive? Is it real, does it work? Is it reasonable to generate Java classes from .RNG?

**Q2:**
Is there a Relaxer for .NET?  Is there a tool that generates C# classes from RelaxNG schema?

**Q3:**   Is there a Relaxer for Javascript?

AND, finally

**Q4:**
Is RelaxNG alive? Is it viable?  Relevant and useful in the REST/JSON world?  Are people still using it or is it going to fade, a good idea that has been dropped?   I know that is subjective, but I'd like to know your assessment.  I see only 9 or 10 RelaxNG Q's on stackoverflow, so I question the relevance of this technology.  If not RelaxNG, then what?  WADL?  *Nothing*?

---

See [Maintaining Consistency Between JavaScript and C# Object Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112958) for a related question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than let this question hang out here unanswered forever, and going on the theory that *no answer at all* is actually a pretty definitive answer, I'm going to provide a response myself.

The answers:

1. No, by all indications, Relaxer is not alive.
2. There is no Relaxer for .NET
3. There is no Relaxer for Javascript
4. RelaxNG is apparently <strike>also dead</strike> still alive, just looking deadish as it is stable, but it is used quite a lot as alternative to XSD. A recent addition was [RelaxNG validation in Saxon for XQuery and XSLT](http://cfoster.net/saxon-jing) done by Charles Foster.
5. There are a bunch of alternatives for RelaxNG validation in .NET, as mentioned in the comments and Martin's answer.

Comment: I've successfully been using Tenuto as a RelaxNG validator for .NET. It is listed here: http://www.relaxng.org/

Comment: For what it's worth, Trang seems to do a lot of what Relaxer did, and is actively maintained: http://code.google.com/p/jing-trang/

Comment: I have a specificiation for a Message Schema written in RelaxNG Compact format which I have to convert to an XSD. Yes people care. ftp://medical.nema.org/medical/dicom/final/sup95_ft.pdf

Comment: I do use Relax-NG, and I'd like to find a living .NET validator for it.

Comment: By the way, Relax-NG itself seems to be just fine as it is, so there is little need for maintenance.

Answer (score 10):

Just use Mono's RelaxngValidatingReader.

I've made a [NuGet Package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/RelaxNG/) by compiling the [Mono Commons.Xml.Relaxng project](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/Commons.Xml.Relaxng).

PS: I use this in production for some [AlpineBits](http://www.alpinebits.org/) projects.

```
XmlReader instance = new XmlTextReader ("instance.xml");
XmlReader grammar = new XmlTextReader ("grammar.rng");
using (RelaxngValidatingReader reader = new RelaxngValidatingReader (instance, grammar)) {
    try {
        while (!reader.EOF) {
            reader.Read();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("validation succeeded");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("validation failed with message:");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any documentation for the project? Like how to use it? In `Documentation/en` I see some XML documentation, but is there a rendered (HTML) version?

Comment: @FranklinYu Added a simple example how to validate a xml file. Also see the [unit tests](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Commons.Xml.Relaxng/Test/RelaxngValidatingReaderTests.cs) in the mono repository.

Comment: Thank you. I thought there is some documentation of `Commons.Xml.Relaxng` online available, since there is [one for most parts of Mono](http://docs.go-mono.com/). I still think that some documentation would improve, and may try adding that into the mono repository via pull request. (Or maybe ask about it in [mailing list](https://lists.dot.net/mailman/listinfo/mono-docs-list).)