# At least 1 input required in XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

This is my input structure to the API,'search serves'

> ```
> <structure name="SearchServesInput" >
> <member name="ClientUser" target="Username" />
> <member name="OwnerUser" target="Username" />
> <member name="ServiceName" target="String" />
> <member name="EnableSearch" target="Boolean" />
> <member name="PanControls" target="PanControls" />   </structure>
> ```

At least 1 of the first three fields is required. How do I implement that?

Comment: i think you have to declare a schema. May be you can watch the answer there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777352/xml-schema-can-i-make-some-of-an-attributes-values-be-required-but-still-allow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to declare a schema, here is a small example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema>
<xs:attribute name="test" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:schema>
```

You can check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp) some tutorials.