# .Net and RelaxNG Schemas

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, relaxng

a few weeks ago I started to use [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx)

for create classes for serialization/deserialization xml files based on the xsd schema.
Currently I am finding util like xsd.exe for create classes from RelaxNG Schemas. Can you help me to find it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Don't bet the farm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113137/is-there-a-relaxer-for-net-is-relaxer-alive-is-relaxng-viable). But there **may** be other proxy generation tools.

Comment: Yes, I saw, comments that is : There is no Relaxer for .NET, And After that I asked this question.