# It´s possible to use Relax NG in Visual Studio?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, relaxng

I want to build a schema for xml, and for what I´ve searched, Relax NG gives better solutions than xmlSchema (xsd).
Is there any way to use it in Visual Studio instead of xmlSchema?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [RelaxngValidatingReader](http://www.nuget.org/packages/RelaxNG/)? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16347104/1712389

Comment: That doesn't help in the XML editor, though; only in programs.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Also, the original poster asked the same question on the Microsoft forums, but didn't get a helpful reply: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b60046e9-e6e7-40a1-8883-61ab30eb2e41/its-possible-to-use-relax-ng-in-visual-studio?forum=visualstudiogeneral