# Is WADL a standard for REST applications?

Tags: java, jersey, wadl

Is WADL a real standard like WSDL?
Must WADL URI end with ".wadl" extension?

I've created an HelloWorld example in Jersey and I've got the WADL from URL.
Then I've created a client using "wadl-client-plugin" and it works.

My question is this:
if I use another framework (i.e. CXF) that generate WADL, can I use it in my "wadl-client-plugin" to create the client?

Answer (score 4):

The REST approach is simpler than SOAP, but unfortunately there is no standard at the moment.

More specifically, concerning WADL, the [W3 team answered](http://www.w3.org/Submission/2009/03/Comment):

> W3C is pleased to receive the Web Application Description Language from SUN Microsystems Inc. 
>   As of today, W3C has no plans to take up work based on this Submission. We encourage people interested by this work to discuss on the public-web-http-desc@w3.org Mailing List

However, there are ways to [create clients from WADL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159881/restful-client-from-wadl)

Comment: Thank you for reply. My idea is to create an eclipse plugin to generate my client. In the wizard you can choose the endpoint (WADL URL) and create client class.

Comment: I'm using jersey API to create the class client in the plugin.

Comment: If you are interesting in Eclipse plugin to generate a java client class from WADL, you can see at link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159881/restful-client-from-wadl/16709008#16709008