# Spring tool to generate Rest Client

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, spring-mvc, wadl

I need to generate Rest client using a wadl. I am aware of wadl2java maven plugin & command line tool provided by Apache-cxf.

However, I could not find any such tool provided by Spring. Does spring provides any plugin to generate client classes using a wadl?

Answer (score 0):

There is a rudimentary client-side code generator from WADL available with Apache CXF JAX-RS implementation http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-description.html

It generates some boilerplate code, but it is nothing close to client generators for SOAP/WSDL web services.

Comment: Hi Manaf, Thanks for your reply. As i said, i am aware of this feature provided by cxf. But i was looking for any such support from Spring. As we are using Spring mvc in our projects to write RESTFul web-services, we are looking if we can write our RESTFul clients using the same technology.

Comment: If you are interesting in Eclipse plugin to generate a java client class from WADL, you can see at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159881/restful-client-from-wadl/16709008#16709008

Comment: Unable to install this plugin in Eclipse Luna. Tried every possible way- Update Site, local install using archive, dropping into dropins folder.

Answer (score 0):

Spring- rest has RestTemplate class for synchronous client calls. [Link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html)
That is quite generic and caters to all the requirements. Like the previous comments there's a few third party wadl2java maven plugins that can be integrated but nothing out of the box.

Comment: Thanks Ashok. I am aware of third party wadl2java maven plugin. I wish Spring too provides java2wadl and wadl2java features like cxf & jersey.