# How to generate JavaScript client stub from WADL?

Tags: javascript, rest, stub, netbeans-plugins, wadl

I want to generate a JavaScript stub for invoking the RESTful web service defined in this wadl: 
http://idi.fundacionctic.org/mobSerenoaWS/application.wadl

I tried with the [NetBeans REST Web Service plugin](http://netbeans.org/features/web/web-services.html) on NetBeans 7.0.1. 
I downloaded the Wadl in my file system and started the JavaScript stub generation. 
It generated many JavaScript files, but they are incomplete. For instance the object `resources` is an empty array.

Can you please tell me what I'm missing to generate a running JavaScript stub with NetBeans? Or do you know any other tool to generate a JavaScript stub from WADL?

Note: NetBeans include a full running sample:

> New Project/samples/Java Web Services/REST: Customer Database

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't find one though you could manually build that API with my plugin [jquery.rest](http://www.github.com/jpillora/jquery.rest). I could add WADL parsing to it though it seems not very popular - [Why the slow WADL uptake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452750/why-the-slow-wadl-uptake). I'll add an issue for it and if it gets some +1s I'll spend some time on it.

Comment: It's a bummer that there's isn't any tools for rest clients generation :(